# Shading artifact after rendering

Tags: shaders, artifacts

I'm now working on a model, it looks fine in the view port, but grey part Shading artifact after rendering to image, here the first screen shot is wire frame, and the second image is rendering result it looks wired, can anyone tell me why? And what strange more is ,when I move the model a little, the artifact gone, I've got no idea what could be the reason.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You said moving it fixes the problem could that mean you accidentally duplicated the object and there's a second one with the same mesh causing z-fighting? Try selecting and deleting it to see if it fixes it.

Comment: The problem is happening because the Bool operations are leaving your 2 top faces as massive n-gon's. You will have  to re-topologize manually to convert the mesh back to primarily quads. A pain - I know, but bools are notorious for leaving messy topology. Fixing it will solve the shading errors.